# Hover images effect

Tags: jquery

i need similar script to this - http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/358_jquery/example%20files/all-examples.html

This works if images have the same resolution, but I have images with different width.

have a similar script, where the resolution does not matter?

Comment: What HTML mark-up, what images and what script? Could you put what you've got into a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), so's we can see what you're using in action?

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize in order to suit your needs

See this: http://blog.jquery.com/2007/05/09/fisheye-dock-menu/